# Implement String.prototype.toLowerCase()

Tags: code-golf, javascript

**Implement `String.prototype.toLowerCase()`**

**Description**

The `toLowerCase` method returns the value of the string converted to `lowercase`. toLowerCase does not affect the value of the string itself.

**Conditions**
Let count chars inside function and ignore all bootstrap code:

```
String.prototype.toLowerCase = function(){
  // code that count here
}
```

Other languages are welcome but JavaScript implemantation is target of this question. Let's just focus on ASCII charachters .

Example input and output:

```
"sOmeText".toLowerCase(); => "sometext"
```

Example implementation:

```
String.prototype.toLowerCase = function(){
  return this.split('').map(function(c){
     var cc = c.charCodeAt(0);
     if (cc > 64 && cc < 91) {
        return String.fromCharCode(cc + 32);
     }
     return c;
  }).join('');
}
```

Comment: Winning condition? I saw `String.prototype.toLowerCase.apply(new Date());` on StackOverflow with a quick search; what is the input going to be?

Comment: @beary605 I've updated the question. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: The example answer is buggy. It doesn't even handle the whole of Latin 1.

Comment: It might want to be specified that the answer only has to work on ASCII characters.  Otherwise, things may get out of hand quickly.

Comment: updated again. JavaScript supports unicode chars and involving that can be confusing. How would you lowercase `Ú`?

Comment: `ú`, obviously. That's what `String.prototype.toLowerCase()` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Javascript <strike>70</strike> 68

Building from @grc's answer:

```
for(s=i='';c=this[i++];s+=(parseInt(c,36)||c).toString(36));return s
```

Convert character to integer then back (works since `Number.toString(36)` will always be lowercase)

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/Vh2TW/2/

input:

```
console.log('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890~`-=_+{}[]:;\\\'\"<>,.?/!@#$%^&*()abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.toLowerCase())
```

output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890~`-=_+{}[]:;\'"<>,.?/!@#$%^&*()abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

**Update:** -2 characters, thanks @copy

Comment: Save 2 characters: `for(s=i=""`

Comment: @copy didn't realize `''++` becomes `0` interesting.

Answer (score 4):

### Bash, 10

Doesn't interface with javascript very well, but it works for everyday purposes.

```
tr A-Z a-z
```

Also, it's shorter than golfscript.  (Booyah!)

---

**Example Input:**

```
echo "Hello World, asDFghJkL0123" | tr A-Z a-z
```

**Output:**

```
hello world, asdfghjkl0123
```

Comment: Kindly show an example of input and output.

Comment: `shorter than golfscript.` This is a first. Is this a first?

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript, 17

```
{..64>\91<*32*|}%
```

Answer (score 2):

### J, 25

```
toLowerCase =: u:@(+32*91&>*64&<)@(3&u:)
```

Converting to numbers `(3&u:)` and back `u:` is quite uneasy.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, 86

```
String.prototype.toLowerCase = function () {
    s="";for(i=0;c=this.charCodeAt(i++);s+=String.fromCharCode(c>64&c<91?c+32:c));return s
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python (45)

`l=lambda x:''.join(chr(ord(i)+('@'<i<'[')*32)for i in x)`

Pseudocode:

```
l=func(x) {
  return toString( iterate(i in x) { chr(ord(i) + IsUppercase(i) * 32) } )
}
```

Explanation:
`('@'<i<'[')*32)`: `IsUppercase.` '@' - 64, 'A' - 65, 'Z' - 90, '[' - 91: If `64<ord(i)<91`, then return True and multiply it by 32 (to get `32`).

Answer (score 0):

### VBA - 77 <strike>82</strike>

```
Function l(s)
'Counting only the stuff between Function and End
For x=1 To Len(s):m=Mid(s,x,1):l=l & IIf(m Like"[A-Z]",Chr(Asc(m)+32),m):Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby: 32 characters

```ruby
s.gsub(/[A-Z]/){($&.ord+32).chr}
```

Sample run:
(In 35 characters it can be made a method of `String` class, to work just as the JavaScript sample.)

```
irb(main):001:0> class String
irb(main):002:1>   def toLowerCase  
irb(main):003:2>     self.gsub(/[A-Z]/){($&.ord+32).chr}
irb(main):004:2>   end
irb(main):005:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> "sOmeText".toLowerCase      
=> "sometext"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### javascript 76 chars:

```
replace(/[A-Z]/g,function(b){return String.fromCharCode(b.charCodeAt()+32)})
```

Here's the full function:

```
String.prototype.toLowerCase = function () {
    return this.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(b){
        return String.fromCharCode(b.charCodeAt()+32)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 49 chars

```
L(s)=ascii([s[i]+32(64<s[i]<91)for i=1:endof(s)])
```

for all chars s[i] if 64 < s[i] < 91 is true, add 32 to the ASCII character point (32*true=32). If it’s false, then (32*false=0), and nothing is changed.

example:

```
julia> str
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz~"

julia> L(str)
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz~"
```

The default method in Julia is lowercase(str)

```
julia> lowercase(str)
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz~"
```

the difference in timing and memory allocation:

```
julia> @time L(str)
elapsed time: 1.0263e-5 seconds (792 bytes allocated)

julia> @time lowercase(str)
elapsed time: 6.693e-6 seconds (224 bytes allocated)
```